# node.js SET HEADER ERROR ON upload to any host

Tags: node.js, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I have a problem with node.js html-pdf,
its give me the error SET HEADER ERROR,

when I upload a file to any host like Amazon EC2
its give me `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client`, but it works very will on my device host `http://localhost:3000`

that makes me confused about how to solve this problem

```
const pdfTemplate = require('./documents');
var options = { orientation: "landscape",format: "A4", };

app.post('/create-pdf', (req, res) => {
  let fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');

  pdf.create(pdfTemplate(req.body, fullUrl), options).toFile('result.pdf', (err) => {
      if(err) {
          res.send(Promise.reject());
      } 
      else {
        res.send(Promise.resolve());
      }
  });   
});
```

Comment: Does it make any sense to call `Promise.resolve()` and `Promise.reject()` if you didn't create any Promise beforehand? And what should return a route handler in these two cases?

Comment: I don't really know what they do, I just copy it from the site,

Comment: What site? Can you get a link?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bt1tOhUYxvM

Comment: start from 17:35,  he put the `Promise` values

Comment: I watched and it still does not make sense at all for me. You can just do: `if(err) {
          res.status(400).send('Error creating PDF');
      } 
      else {
        res.status(200).send('OK');
      }`

Comment: And please add a response from your request

Comment: thx i will try this code